# How do I fix a Corrupted csproj file?

Tags: xml, git, visual-studio, rebase, csproj

I'm in a group working on a project, and was about to Rebase my branch with the new updates from master-branch using git. When rebase started, it suddenly breaks down and gives me this error message:

```
The project file could not be loaded. Name cannot 
begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C.
Line 173, position 2.
```

The "csproj" file seems to be corrupted. How can i fix this? The problem looks like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\AccountController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\CategoryController.cs" />
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <Compile Include="Controllers\GalleryController.cs" />
=======
    <Compile Include="Controllers\CheckoutController.cs" />
>>>>>>> Checkout Works. something wrong with Authorization. No need be logged
    <Compile Include="Controllers\HomeController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\ManageController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\PhotoController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\ShoppingCartController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\StoreController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\StoreManagerController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
```

Comment: was it an interactive rebase? Is it okay to delete all project-related files and reimport project? (try with a backup)

Comment: by the way, csproj and other IDE-related files are usually not under version control. They should be added to .gitignore

Comment: @NickVolynkin Hi. Tried reimporting the project. With no luck. Still gets the error message, and is stuck on "rebase 1/2". Are you saying that the csproj should not in the main files? Should i delete it?

Comment: try `git rebase --abort` ?

Comment: That would abort, and the project would go back to normal. But the problem remains. Still need to rebase and commit changes to the project.

Comment: After a while I found a solution for this. Turns out its pretty straight forward. Checkout this if you have the same problem:
[github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: @NickVolynkin csproj files are definitely candidates for source control.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: are you crazy? Projects and such should very _much_ be under source control. If they had been source controlled, then the OP would not have this problem!

Answer (score 21):

Just delete below type of text's in csproj file

***<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

---------Mine

'>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>***

And reload project again it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I agree Chrisaboo. The problem is in the project file. Whenever you update your solution in Visual Studio, there is a possibility of a merge conflict. You can resolve this by comparing your project file with the previous version and eliminating the differences in a text editor or the version control tool. 
This resolved the issue for me.

It is recommended to update the project on a folder level in Visual Studio rather than the solution level.

Comment: It merge conflict issue, Its working fine after removing 
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
>>>>>>> Checkout Works. something wrong with Authorization. No need be logged

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such a problem when I want to merge with my friend on a ASP.NET MVC project, and the problem is that when I use git to merge our project, there are several differences in the file of .csproject so that I cannot open the project;

Finally I open the file by using sublime and find that the problem is that I have added sevaral css stylesheet to the project, then I repair the merge conflict in the csproject file and open the project and finally solve other conflicts in the project.